# datetimepicker opening drop down causes application to exit

Tags: c#, winforms

this is the craziest thing I have ever seen

I have a simple app with nothing in it except a datetimepicker.

If I run the app inside VS(2013-2017) and open the calendar popup everything works fine.

If I compile the app (debug or release) and run it the application closes as soon as I click on the calendar icon.

There are no exceptions reported, attaching to running process does not catch any exception putting in the unhandled exception catch all does not catch anything on the UI or the application thread.

The application targets .NET 4.5.1 with any cpu. Same result if I target x86 or 64.

I am thinking it's probably some security policy or something along those lines but don't know enough about this to pose a correct question to the security team.

Here is the log from Debug Diagnostic Tool: 
Loading control script C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\scripts\CrashRule_Process_WindowsFormsApp1.exe.vbs DumpPath set to C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Crash rule for all instances of WindowsFormsApp1.exe

[6/13/2017 11:40:42 AM] 
Process created. BaseModule - C:\Users\developer1\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe. BaseThread - System ID: 9468

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll loaded at 0x774f0000
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 8472
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 14748
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 12908
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 14436
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 5704
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 5880
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 7596
 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL loaded at 0x74ad0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll loaded at 0x769f0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll loaded at 0x76e60000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll loaded at 0x76fa0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll loaded at 0x753b0000
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll loaded at 0x75460000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll loaded at 0x750d0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll loaded at 0x74d90000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll loaded at 0x74d80000
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll loaded at 0x74a50000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll loaded at 0x751e0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll loaded at 0x77060000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll loaded at 0x752a0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll loaded at 0x769e0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll loaded at 0x766e0000
 C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL loaded at 0x75240000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll loaded at 0x76ec0000
 C:\Windows\system32\ctiuser.dll loaded at 0x749d0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll loaded at 0x75050000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll loaded at 0x75480000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL loaded at 0x774c0000
 C:\Windows\system32\FLTLIB.DLL loaded at 0x749c0000
 C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll loaded at 0x749b0000
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll loaded at 0x742f0000
 C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll loaded at 0x741f0000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\50bcbedc6ed7027bd709339d3ec4c388\mscorlib.ni.dll loaded at 0x730a0000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll loaded at 0x76560000
 C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll loaded at 0x6cdd0000
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll loaded at 0x73020000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll loaded at 0x76dc0000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\48fb602d35146bc0c0002b21343a9f56\System.ni.dll loaded at 0x72690000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\d59cbbb217b18f4219761e344ccf1c10\System.Drawing.ni.dll loaded at 0x6a610000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\a615de88390374e7e71749451bfa5eaf\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll loaded at 0x653c0000
 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_ec86b8d6858ec0bc\comctl32.dll loaded at 0x71c90000
 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\comctl32.dll loaded at 0x6cc30000
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll loaded at 0x72270000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\a514635984ff3f4239dc0421b7e024b9\System.Core.ni.dll loaded at 0x68370000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\a11c194343da7333f7f7e38960758384\System.Configuration.ni.dll loaded at 0x6ab30000
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\43529c5402fb2a8ebc8c76877b802cdc\System.Xml.ni.dll loaded at 0x68f70000
 C:\Windows\syswow64\shell32.dll loaded at 0x75490000

C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.23721_none_5c052bcda00f9399\gdiplus.dll loaded at 0x6b010000
 C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll loaded at 0x6ecc0000
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 6124
 Initializing control script
 Clearing any existing breakpoints

 Current Breakpoint List(BL)
 [6/13/2017 11:40:43 AM]
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 6124. Exit code - 0x00000000
 [6/13/2017 11:41:11 AM]
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 14984
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll loaded at 0x74c20000
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll loaded at 0x74be0000
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll loaded at 0x74bd0000
 Thread created. New thread - System ID: 13868
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 12908. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 13868. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 14984. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 7596. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 5704. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 5880. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 14436. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 14748. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Thread exited. Exiting thread - System ID: 8472. Exit code - 0x00000001
 Process exited. Exit code - 0x00000001

 Debugging Overhead Cost:
 Total Elapsed Ticks = 28767 (100%)
 Total Ticks Spent in Debugger Engine = 920 (3%)
 Total Ticks Spent in Crash Rule Script = 63 (0%)

Comment: Any code in the drop down events, etc?

Comment: If you're writing to the console and one doesn't exist, that could cause a failure, but I believe it would throw an exception.  That is one of the cases where running through the debugger works while running command-line fails.  Outside of that, they link different libraries; it's possible your stand-alone libraries somehow got corrupted, and you may need to re-install VS.

Comment: Nope. I created a simple demo app with no code in it just a DateTimePicker on the main form and same result.

Comment: @TriStar, Try to work up an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code.  I just tried this (one-form app with nothing but a `DateTimePicker`) and it works fine for me in or out of the debugger.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein it's reproducible on multiple pc's in the domain.

Comment: it works for me with no issues on other computers just not in the domain.  Which makes me thinks it's some sort of security policy.

Comment: Here is the log from Debug Diagnostic Tool:

Comment: when you test outside of VS are you running the debug build or a release build?  If it is reproducible on multiple machines; but not all of them correct?  If so, on the machines, are you an admin and if not on the machines it does run from, are they an admin?

Comment: @Sorceri I am a local admin on all the tested machines. I have run both debug and release builds.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue.  However, we have released the application for years without issue.  After our most recent release some workstations have this issue and others don't.  The program crashes after clicking the drop down for DateTimePicker.  We are targeting .NET v3.5 and can not currently move to 4 or 4.5.   Was hoping you found something?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a breakpoint for any of your DateTimePicker's events? If so, remove the breakpoint(s), and the problem should stop. This is a known issue per Microsoft Windows Forms Team on this page: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1290685/debugging-datetimepicker-event-hangs-vs:

"The DateTimePicker control installs a mouse hook as part of its functionality, but when the debugger has the WinForms application stopped on a breakpoint, it allows the possibility of a deadlock if VS happens to get a mouse message. For now, the deadlock is unfortunately a consequence of the DateTimePicker's design. The mouse hook is installed when the drop down is clicked to display the calendar. **This means that breakpoints should not be sent in any event handlers which would be called while the calendar is active.** We are currently investigating whether it is possible to address this issue and we will update this thread with further information if we are able to make a fix available."

Answer (score 1):

Well,  I had a very similar experience.  Only some clients had this issue.  It was caused by their anti-virus program (CarbonBlack in my case).

In the event log I found this entry by "CbDefense" EventId:17

'Information: The application "MYEXEPATH" attempted to inject code into the process "MYEXEPATH" by calling the function "SetWindowsHookExW".  The operation was blocked and the application terminated by Confer.'

If they clicked on WinForm DateTimePicker it would crash the program.

(Was built targeting C# .NET 3.5)

Comment: What did you do then to fix this issue in clients ?

Comment: I believe they were able to add an exception in CarbonBlack.  I did not actually correct the client machine.  Once we told the IT department what the issue was they corrected it.

Comment: Thank you, i just had this issue in customer as well. I found out that carbon black is identifying the signed application. So if the application is not signed, any small changes will make this blocked. so, unsigned application will need to re-add the file in the exception of cbdefense.